# Regular expression is not working in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

I am using regular expression in my mvc project but its not working. It is always showing error.
can anyone tell me is it correct or not if yes then why is not working.
Thats is my Model.

```
public partial class State
    {
        public int StateId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [RegularExpression(@"^(([A-za-z]+[\s]{1}[A-za-z]+))$", ErrorMessage = "State Name must be alphabetic")]
        public string StateName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Range(1, 10)]
        public Nullable<int> CountryId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> startdate { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: What do you expect to be valid/not valid? And I assume you mean `[A-Za-z]`, not `[A-za-z]`

Comment: is not working. when i type State name is Rajasthan then error message is showing

Comment: [A-Za-z] : It means Capital `A to Z` and small `a to z` character will be supported in your text. u have written incorrectly.

Comment: `Rajasthan` wont match - your requiring one or more alfa characters followed by one whitespace character followed by one or more alfa characters

Comment: @StephenMuecke now is working. But i dont want to use white space in my text box

Comment: Then what are the rules you want to apply? `[\s]{1}` means one whitespace character!

Comment: @DurgpalSingh if u dont add white space in the state field then how do u write Jammu and Kashmir or Jammu Kashmir?

Comment: `/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/` will work for you. ie. Rajesthan, Gujarat, Jammu and Kashmir, etc.

Comment: @Nimesh is showing error
/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/

Comment: remove forward slash if you have added `@`. you can try it [here](http://rubular.com/r/MkvCKBYQ49).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69014/discussion-between-durgpal-singh-and-nimesh).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the expression ^[A-za-z]+(([\s]{1})?[A-za-z])+$

You can use http://rubular.com/ to validate regular expression.

Comment: But this will accept a whitespace without any other character included and name having whitespace at the beginning? Is this valid in your case?

Comment: No its not compulsory to define white space in this text box. if you want to define its ok otherwise not compulsory. And its working fine. And if i used your code then its take a while space 
ex:- if i type Rajasthan then its showing error

Comment: It accepts Rajsthan without any space because I have used "?" (zero or more) for whitespace. So it will accept a name without any whitespace.

Comment: @DurgpalSingh You can post your answer your self. So, other user also don't get confused about ur question is still open and not resolved yet.

Comment: May be its right. but my code is working now. So thanks 
@Anuja